# Nested Parameterized types in interface

Tags: java, generics, parameterized

I have following interfaces:

**CacheKey interface:**

```
public interface CacheKey<K extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
    K get();
}
```

**CacheValue interface:**

```
public interface CacheValue<V extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
    V get();
}
```

**Cache interface:**

```
public interface Cache<CacheKey<K extends Serializable>, CacheValue<V extends Serializable>> {
}
```

Cache interface doesn't compile. Error I get is:
[13,35] > expected

i.e. after CacheKey compiler doesn't like another opening angle bracket:

```
public interface Cache<CacheKey<
                               ^
```

Is this not possible in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a crucial step here : the implementation.

It's usually in the implementation that you want to define what the type of `? extends Serializable` will be. You don't need to implement this in the `Cache` interface.

The interface only needs to know what its generics types will be, not the generics of their child : this is for the implementation.

Take a look at the example here below to understand what I exactly mean by that.

Addition : When your define something like `Cache<CacheKey, CacheValue>` you're not referring to the classes, but you're creation a generic alias. `CacheKey` could easily be replaced by `Blabla` and continue to have the same behaviour. The solution is to use `extends` to make sure we're talking about the type.

This was also the reason why `Cache<CacheKey<...>>` did not compile, because `CacheKey` is not referring to the class but is used as an alias

```
public interface CacheKey<K extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
    K get();
}

public interface CacheValue<V extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
    V get();
}

public interface Cache<K extends CacheKey<? extends Serializable>, V extends CacheValue<? extends Serializable>> {
    void put(K key, V value);
}

public class CacheImpl implements Cache<CacheKey<String>, CacheValue<String>> {
    @Override
    public void put(CacheKey<String> key, CacheValue<String> value) {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: `K extends CacheKey` and `V extends CacheValue` will generate compiler warnings due to the use of raw types, which negates the entire benefit of using generics.

Comment: @VGR Are you sure about the warnings? I'm not sure about losing the benefits of working with generics, since the implementation enforces them..

Comment: @VGR It does not issue any warning, but I modified the code nonetheless, for clarity and also by explicitly putting the generic type, you enforce the implementation to not work with raw types. But no warning issued.

Comment: Try compiling with all warnings enabled.  On the command line, that is done with `-Xlint`.  When I do it, I get `Cache.java:12: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: CacheKey`.

Comment: Thanks YassinHajaj - Your subsequent update led me to right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a wildcard-bounded generic type, as suggested in other answers, isn't a great idea.

If you declare your class like this:

```
public interface Cache<K extends CacheKey<?>, V extends CacheValue<?>> {
}
```

then you would never be able to usefully invoke `get()` on the key or value, because they would only ever return `Serializable`. And `Serializable` is a *useless* class (it's barely different to `Object` actually inside your code).

Instead, I would simply declare the class like:

```
public interface Cache<K extends Serializable, V extends Serializable> {
```

and then declare that the `put` method takes a `CacheKey<K>` and a `CacheValue<V>`:

```
  void put(CacheKey<K> key, CacheValue<V> value);
```

because, ultimately, all implementations of `CacheKey<K>` and `CacheValue<V>` should be indistinguishable.

If you *really* want to force the `CacheKey<K>` and `CacheValue<V>` to be of specific types, you need to add more type variables:

```
public interface Cache<
    K extends Serializable, CK extends CacheKey<K>,
    V extends Serializable, CV extends CacheValue<V>> {
  void put(CK key, CV value);
}
```

but this is really quite gross, as you would have to carry around all of these 4 type variables wherever you use a `Cache` type directly.

Of course, you can specialize the interface to hide some of these type variables:

```
interface StringKey extends CacheKey<String> {}
interface IntegerValue extends CacheValue<Integer> {}
interface StringIntegerCache extends Cache<String, StringKey, Integer, IntegerValue> {}
```

and then just use `StringIntegerCache`. The usefulness of doing so depends on your application.